# Cant deploy auth provider from Sandbox with RegistrationHandler

Tags: authentication

I'm trying to deploy an auth provider from sandbox, and it seems like I'm running into a catch 22.

The Execution User is set to my sandbox user - it has the exact same ID as my prod user, but of course the username is different.

And so on deploying to prod, I get the following error:

> In field: ExecutionUser - no User named gsxx@xxxxxx.org.ssotest found

So it seems like its not possible to deploy an Auth Provider with a registration handler defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach is to remove the RegistrationHandler, which then allows you to blank out the Execution User and deploy. Then you only need to set the registration handler and execution user in production.

Comment: I don't know about that.. I tried dropping the RegHandler and it gave me 'You must enter a value' --- and I think the question was about DEPLOYING, not about manually setting things in Prod.......

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, but ExecuteAs(Execution User) still required field, So cant save blank.

What i did is, i just deployed RegistrationHandler, Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass, and manually created the AuthProvider record in Production with selecting the Custom AuthProvider name from drop down.